# Use of $at register in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, computer-architecture, mips

Register r1 or $at, is it's sole use in pseudoinstructions? If so, is this the sole solution to enable pseudoinstructions within the architecture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the $at (Assembler Temporary) register is generally reserved for use in pseudoinstructions.

That's not to say you can't use it yourself for other things, but don't rely on it being kept the same from instruction to instruction if you use pseudoinstructions (which sometimes you use without realising it).

To protect your other registers it's important that the assembler doesn't use any other registers for pseudoinstructions, so if it's well behaved (and they all should be, or things would break) then it will always use $at.

Comment: How does other architectures solve this problem? Same solution?

Comment: Yes. For example, ARM uses R0 for both expanding pseudoinstructions, and for return values from functions. It's not given a specific label, but it's part of the "calling convention" of ARM.